# How to return data when a file is uploaded with igUpload control

Tags: infragistics, ignite-ui

I'm using upload control in the following manner:

```
uploadContainer.igUpload({
        mode: 'multiple',
        multipleFiles: true,
        maxSimultaneousFilesUploads: 2,
        maxUploadedFiles: 2048,
        labelUploadButton: "Choose File",
        labelAddButton: "Choose File",
        labelClearAllButton: null,
        autostartupload: true,
        onError: function(e, args) {...some function...},
        fileUploaded: function(e, args) {...some function...},
        allowedExtensions: ['dwg', 'DWG']
    });
```

- Current user, when arrives on the page, could upload a file.
- After uploading, he expects some information to be returned from uploaded
  file.I have to display list of layouts of the dwg file per example.
- Into my upload handler class at the back-end, "FinishedUpload" method
  is called. There, I'm reading the file, extracting some information
  from it and I want to return this information back to the front-end.

How to accomplish that? Any ideas are welcomed!

Thank you!

Comment: How to get HTTP Response headers that are returned during the upload process? It is possible to hide some data there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information to send additional data to the server Upload MVC Wrapper and the igUpload control on the client and vice-versa will be available in the Ignite UI June 2015 service release.

What you can do currently is to handle the client-side [fileUploaded](http://help.infragistics.com/jQuery/2015.1/ui.igupload#events:fileUploaded) event and send an additional Ajax request to the server to get the data you want.

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing :) Looking forward to the next release!